# Query ignores order when there's multiple left_joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I’m trying to order `Posts` by their conversion rate which is represented by `unique commenters/impressions`.  The query I have does the calculation, but ordering by that calculation fails.  After looking into it, it seems that the `order` breaks when I join on two tables even if the query is otherwise the same.  Here’s a minimal example:

```
# Works as expected
Post.left_joins(:impressions)
  .group(:id)
  .order("count(impressions) DESC")

# Orders seemingly randomly
Post.left_joins(:comments, :impressions)
  .group(:id)
  .order("count(impressions) DESC")
```

Here is the generated SQL from these queries:

```
-- Works as expected
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "impressions" ON "impressions"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
  GROUP BY "posts"."id" 
  ORDER BY count(impressions) DESC

-- Seemingly random order
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "impressions" ON "impressions"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
  GROUP BY "posts"."id" 
  ORDER BY count(impressions) DESC
```

I'm using Postgres and Rails 5.2

---

In reality, the query would be more like this:

```
Post.left_joins(:comments, :impressions)
  .group(:id)
  .order("cast(count(distinct(comments.user_id)) AS float) / cast(greatest(count(impressions), 1) AS float) DESC")
```

However, the minimal example displays the unintuitive behavior I've been seeing.

---

Is this expected?  And if so, how would this be worked around?

Comment: How do you count **impressions** without specifiying the column ?
`cast(greatest(count(impressions), 1)`

Comment: @Shiko It appears to count all associated rows whether I specify a column or not. The calculation appears to be happening as expected, but the ordering is what's not working

Comment: It is weird, an alternative way is to use `sort_by` once you got the results from AR. https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by

Comment: @Shiko The only issue with that is I need to return an AR relation so I can do further queries on it

Comment: what is the generated SQL please ?

Comment: @Shiko I've added it to the main question body

Comment: I tried similar query on my side, and results are correct, I have the feelings that your issue is with `distinct(comments.user_id)`, can you add it to the `group` chain and try.